# Deserializing a different List with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a problem with deserialization Protobuf-net. I serialize a `List<>` but when I deserialize the `List<>` returned is not identical to the first. There is missing data.
I do not understand why.

I initialize my `List<>` in ctr

```
public ctr()
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(2012 , 12, 03); ;
    LkVisiteurIdDTO visitid= new LkVisiteurIdDTO(10, 11, 12);
    PurgeDateTimeDTO datetime= new PurgeDateTimeDTO(date, true);
    ContractProtoBuf proto = new ContractProtoBuf();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        proto.m_Index = i + 1;
        proto.m_TechnicalKey = "m_TechnicalKey" + i;
        proto.m_LogicalKey = visitid;
        proto.m_PurgeTime = datetime;

        protoContractList.Add(proto);
    }

}

public byte[] serialization()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, protoContractList);
        arr = ms.ToArray();
        return arr;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("La sérialisation protobuf a échoué");
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        ms.Close();
    }

}

public List<ContractProtoBuf> deserialization()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arr,false);
    try
    {             
        listeRetour = Serializer.Deserialize<List<ContractProtoBuf>>(ms);
        return (listeRetour);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("La désérialisation protobuf a échoué");
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        ms.Close();
    }
}
```

So my question is how to have same result ?

---

Here is my structure

```
    [ProtoContract]
public struct ContractProtoBuf
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int m_Index;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string m_TechnicalKey;

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public LkVisiteurIdDTO m_LogicalKey;

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public PurgeDateTimeDTO m_PurgeTime;
 }
```

I create a list of ContractProtoBuf and I add data with values ​​"that do not have consequence."

```
    public ctr()
    {
DateTime date = new DateTime(2012 , 12, 03); ;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    LkVisiteurIdDTO visitid= new LkVisiteurIdDTO(10, 11, 12);
    PurgeDateTimeDTO datetime= new PurgeDateTimeDTO(date, true);
    ContractProtoBuf proto = new ContractProtoBuf();
    proto.m_Index = i + 1;
    proto.m_TechnicalKey = "m_TechnicalKey" + i;
    proto.m_LogicalKey = visitid;
    proto.m_PurgeTime = datetime;

    protoContractList.Add(proto);
}
```

}

I serialize my list that gets a Byte [] and when I deserialize the Byte [], the return list does not contain the same values ​​in the type PurgeDateTimeDTO and LkVisiteurIdDTO .

In the return list I find the dateTime {01/01/0001 0:00:00} and visitid {0,0,0}
However m.Index and m_Technicalkey have good value

Comment: It's very hard to help without seeing an example of the data you're serializing, or what the differences are. It would really help if you could produce a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Re your edit : you say that the `PurgeDateTimeDTO` and `LkVisiteurIdDTO` do not contain the same values... but you have not actually included those for me to reproduce it. I am genuinely interested in helping you find the issue (as a library author, I want people to succeed) - but I can't help without the context.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the DTOs, but if I assume that `ContractProtoBuf` is a `class`, then you are adding the **same** instance each time. Equally, you are adding the same *visit* each time. Normally, I would expect these to be different, for example:

```
public ctr()
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(2012 , 12, 03); ;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        LkVisiteurIdDTO visitid= new LkVisiteurIdDTO(10, 11, 12);
        PurgeDateTimeDTO datetime= new PurgeDateTimeDTO(date, true);
        ContractProtoBuf proto = new ContractProtoBuf();
        proto.m_Index = i + 1;
        proto.m_TechnicalKey = "m_TechnicalKey" + i;
        proto.m_LogicalKey = visitid;
        proto.m_PurgeTime = datetime;

        protoContractList.Add(proto);
    }    
}
```

But as I say - it is impossible to say for sure without more information. If you can provide a *complete* (i.e. *runnable*) example, I'll be happy to look further.